# Save log process from edge to edge with inner catch

Tags: c#, sql-server

I use an example to explain my question:

```
namespace LogQ
{
    public class c1
    {
        public c1()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("C1 Cons");
            LogToSql.writeLog("C1 Cons");
        }

        public void c1function()
        {
            try
            {
                throw new Exception();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("there was Exception in class c1 - method c1function");
                LogToSql.writeLog(ex.ToString);
                throw ex;
            }
        }    
    }

    public class c2
    {
        public c2()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("C2 Cons");
            LogToSql.writeLog("C2 Cons");
        }

        public void c2function()
        {
            try
            {
                c1 cOne = new c1();
                cOne.c1function();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("there was Exception in class c2 - method c2function");
                LogToSql.writeLog(ex.ToString);
            }
        }    
    }

    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            for (int thread = 1; thread < 3; thread++)
            {
                c2 cTwo = new c2();
                cTwo.c2function();
            }                
        }
    }
}
```

How can I write a logs for each process - from start to end, without be confused with other processes?

The output of the above Example is:

> C2 Cons
>
> C1 Cons
>
> there was Exception in class c1 - method c1function
>
> there was Exception in class c2 - method c2function
>
> C2 Cons
>
> C1 Cons
>
> there was Exception in class c1 - method c1function
>
> there was Exception in class c2 - method c2function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you write the log to sql server. So you have some options.

You could prefix all logentries with a certain string like

```
LogToSql.writeLog("C1 Cons");
LogToSql.writeLog("C1 there was Exception in class c1 - method c1function");
```

then you can query the log table like

```
select * from logtable where message like 'C1%'
```

but it would be better to have an extra column and extend your logging so you can do

```
LogToSql.writelog(Thead.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, "message")
```

and then select like

```
select processId, message from logtable where processId = 12
```

In this scenario logging is done per thread, so it is easy to query for logentries per thread.

But there are tons of logging frameworks you can use than can probably do something similar to this.

Comment: thank you very much, the solution with the thread number is brilliant! :)